# mantener información de input cuando se oculta - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

buen dia, tengo dos botones uno se llama "si" y el otro botón se llama "no", al darle clic en el boton "si" este me abre un div con un un "input" tipo text y lo mismo al darle clic en el boton "no", lo que necesito es que se mantenga la información que escriba en los input ya que si escribo algo en alguno de los input y activo el div "si" o  el div "no" lo que haya escrito en los input se borra:

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-voice-di2frw?file=/src/App.js

code:

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function Pruebas3() {

  const [value2, setValue2] = useState("");

  const handlerOnClick = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.value) // si || no
    setValue2(e.target.value)
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
        <div className="form-check">

        <input
            type="button"
            name="boton1"
            value="no"           
            onClick={handlerOnClick}
        /> 
        
  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
          <input
            type="button"
            name="boton1"
            value="si"           
            onClick={handlerOnClick}
          /> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-sm-7">
        {value2 === "si" && (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h1>DIV si</h1>
              <input type="text" name="div1" />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>


      <div className="col-sm-7">
        {value2 === "no" && (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h1>DIV no</h1>
              <input type="text" name="div2" />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes dos `inputs` de tipo `button` que cuando los oprimes te abre el `<div>` y el `<input>` con tipo `text`. Pero no estás **guardando en el estado** el valor de esos inputs de tipo texto.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Puedes crear un estado con `useState` para **cada** input de tipo texto y cada vez se actualice el input, se actualice su estado.
2. O puedes crear un estado con `useState` que guarde el texto de los dos inputs y dependiendo de cuál sea el `name` del input que se actualiza, a ese le aplicamos la actualización de estado.

```js
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    si: "",
    no: ""
  });
```

La función que se encargará de actualizar ese estado:

```js
const handleInputValue = (e) => {
  setInputValue({ ...inputValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

De esta manera podemos setear los inputs como

```js
<div className="card-body">
  <h1>DIV si</h1>
  <input
  onChange={handleInputValue}
  defaultValue={inputValue.si}
  type="text"
  name="si"
  />
</div>
```

Si ves cada `input` tiene una propiedad `name` que identifica al input. Usamos ese prop en `handleInputValue` para asignar el `key` con el `value` => `[e.target.name]: e.target.value` que se traduce a `[si]: e.target.value` o `[no]: e.target.value` en el caso de `no` y actualiza cada key con su respectivo valor.

Puedes ver el [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-dream-3gete6?file=/src/App.js).